# Copy Internal Table value to External table on checkbox click

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<!--External table-->
 <table border="1px">
 <tr>

                   <td>
                   //price and quantity fields
                   <input type="text" name="price" label="Price" id="Pri">
                   <input type="text" name="quantity" label="Quantity" id="Qty">
                   </td>
                   <td>
       <!--internal table-->
     <table border="1px">
                   <tr>
                       <th>Price</th>
                       <th>Quantity</th>
                       <th>Action</th>
                   </tr>
                    <tr>
                       <td>1</td>
                       <td>2</td>
                       <td><input type="checkbox" id="checx"/></td>
                 </tr> 
                        <tr>
                       <td>11</td>
                       <td>22</td>
                       <td><input type="checkbox" id="checx"/></td>
                   </tr> 
                   <tr>
                       <td>111</td>
                       <td>222</td>
                       <td><input type="checkbox" id="checx"/></td>
                   </tr> 
                    <tr>
                       <td>10</td>
                       <td>20</td>
                       <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
                   </tr> 
                   </table>   
                   </td>
                   </tr>

                   </table>
                   //Javascript
                   <script type="text/javascript">       
 checkboxes = document.getElementById("checx").getElementsByTagName("input"); 
for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    var checkbox = checkboxes[i];
    checkbox.onclick = function() {
        var currentRow = this.parentNode.parentNode;
        var secondColumn = currentRow.getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
         var FirstColumn = currentRow.getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
        alert("My text is: " + secondColumn.textContent +" "+ FirstColumn.textContent);
    };
} 
 document.getElementById("Pri").value=secondColumn.textContent;
 document.getElementById("Qty").value=FirstColumn.textContent;

       </script>
//I have a dynamic table on the above pattern.I  want in such a way that when I click on the checkbox on the internal table it should copy the values and should show on the input boxes on the corresponding row on the external table.
</body>
</html>
```

I have a dynamic table on the above pattern.I  want in such a way that when I click on the checkbox on the internal table it should copy the values and should show on the input boxes on the corresponding row on the external table.

Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the main issue that checkboxes ids has to be unique per element so you have to depend on class name rather than ids of checkboxes
in addition to the following code

```
document.getElementById("Pri").value=secondColumn.textContent;
document.getElementById("Qty").value=FirstColumn.textContent;
```

Has to be inside the event handler

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<!--External table-->
 <table id="parentTable" border="1px">
 <tr>

                   <td>
                   //price and quantity fields
                   <input type="text" name="price" label="Price" id="Pri">
                   <input type="text" name="quantity" label="Quantity" id="Qty">
                   </td>
                   <td>
       <!--internal table-->
     <table border="1px">
                   <tr>
                       <th>Price</th>
                       <th>Quantity</th>
                       <th>Action</th>
                   </tr>
                    <tr>
                       <td>1</td>
                       <td>2</td>
                       <td><input type="checkbox" id="checx1" class="checx"/></td>
                 </tr> 
                        <tr>
                       <td>11</td>
                       <td>22</td>
                       <td><input type="checkbox" id="checx2" class="checx"/></td>
                   </tr> 
                   <tr>
                       <td>111</td>
                       <td>222</td>
                       <td><input type="checkbox" id="checx3" class="checx"/></td>
                   </tr> 
                    <tr>
                       <td>10</td>
                       <td>20</td>
                       <td><input type="checkbox" id="checx4" class="checx" /></td>
                   </tr> 
                   </table>   
                   </td>
                   </tr>

                   </table>
            //Javascript
                   <script type="text/javascript">       
    checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName("checx"); 
    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
        var checkbox = checkboxes[i];
    checkbox.onclick = function() {
            var currentRow = this.parentNode.parentNode;
            var secondColumn = currentRow.getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
             var FirstColumn = currentRow.getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
            alert("My text is: " + secondColumn.textContent +" "+FirstColumn.textContent);
            document.getElementById("Pri").value=secondColumn.textContent;
            document.getElementById("Qty").value=FirstColumn.textContent;
        };
    } 
       </script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Price and quantity multiple rows will be there how to detect particular row checkbox and copy those value

Comment: @KarthikaRam it is already get current row using  var currentRow = this.parentNode.parentNode; and this here refer to clicked checkbox

Comment: Id will be same for each every row right how it decides based on id not based on current can you please show how to get based on current row not based on ID

Comment: this keyword inside the event handler represents the current clicked checkbox checkbox.onclick = function() { this }; no need to get by id